# Is this type of polyethylene mat ESD safe?

Tags: pcb, safety, esd, metal

I have a few metal keyboards which have a slight risk - if there is too great a charge, it will go through the case and potentially short the PCB inside. Ideally the case is designed well enough to prevent this from happening, but sometimes accidents happen.

I am storing the keyboards in a drawer under my bed, and I want to use some shelf liner, Ikea Variera brand. The site says the materials are "Polyethylene, Synthetic rubber."

Would this be safe to use? I tried to Google around a bit and it does say that polyethylene inhibits the triboelectric charging effect, so it won't easily collect electrons on its surface I think, but I also don't know if the rubber would counteract that since it's an insulator which Google tells me is not ESD safe since that means electrons can't flow through it freely and discharge safely.

So I'm not really sure I understand how to make this call for myself and I am hoping someone else who knows this stuff better can shed some light on it. Thanks!

Comment: If it was ESD safe, you would know it. But show us your metal keyboards. Are they commercial products? If they are, they should have already been designed with this in mind...at least when plugged in anyways. Less certain if this is unplugged storage but that huge metal shell isn't all bad. It helps with the free-space capacitance which allows more charge to be absorbed for the same voltage rise. "*Polyethylene inhibits the triboelectric charging effect*" this sounds like baloney because if this were true then there would be no difference between normal PE and ESD-treated PE

Comment: However, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: Your question is clear in its intent and well-phrased. However, it requires manufacturer's advice.

Comment: triboelectric effects depend greatly bipolar donor/receptor matching materials for friction.  (like wool/glass, neoprene/nylon) Yet PE is a great insulator and unlikely to have the contaminating ingredient to dissipate , but with dust bunnies and humidity maybe... ;)